# push function in perl not adding elements to existing array. why?

Tags: perl, push

My program is

```
#!\usr\bin\perl

@a = (1,2,3);
@b= ("homer", "marge", "lisa", "maria");
@c= qw(one two three);

print push @a, $b; 
print "\n";

@count_number= push @a, $b; 

print @count_number; 
print "\n"; 
print @a;
```

I am getting output as

```
4
5
123
```

Why am I getting the output `4, 5, 123`? Why is my array not extending? And moreover output is not `4, 4, 123` or `5, 5, 123`. Why such behaviour ? Why am I not getting the output `1 2 3 homer marge lisa maria`?

I am a beginner. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of `use strict` and `warnings` [pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html). Your script doesn't work because you don't have anything assigned for `$b` variable, so you are pushing empty values to the array, and as said before you are just printing the number of elements in the array. Also push function only returns the number of the arrays after the new element is pushed to the array if I remember correctly, so returning should always be a scalar.

```
my @a = (1,2,3);
my @b= ("homer", "marge", "lisa", "maria");
my @c= qw(one two three);

#merge the two arrays and count elements
my $no_of_elements = push @a, @b;
print $no_of_elements;

#look into say function, it prints the newline automatically
print "\n";

#use scalar variable to store a single value not an array 
my $count_number= push @a, $b;

print @count_number; print "\n";

print @a;
```

Also interesting fact, if you `print @array` it will list all the elements without spaces, but if you enclose the array in double quotes, `print "@array"`, it will put spaces in between the elements.
Oh and last but not least, if you are new to perl you really really reaaally should download the book of modern perl at http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html, it is updated on yearly basis so you will find there the most up to date practices and code; which definitely beats any outdated online tutorials. Also the book is very well and logically structured and makes learning perl a breeze.

Comment: `strict` would not catch the erroneous `$b` variable, since `$b` is a predefined variable used with `sort`. `warnings` would catch it as undefined value in print, though.

Answer (score 2):

`$b` is undefined.

`@b` and `$b` are different variables. One is a list, the other a scalar.

You are printing the length of the array, and not the contents.

Recommendations:

1. Use "use warnings;"
2. Use "use strict;"
3. Use "push @a, @b;"

Your script:

```
@a = (1,2,3);  # @a contains three elements
@b= ("homer", "marge", "lisa", "maria"); # @b contains 4 elements
@c= qw(one two three); # @c contains 3 elements
print push @a, $b;     # $b is undefined, @a now contains four elements 
                       #(forth one is 'undef'), you print out "4"
print "\n";

@count_number= push @a, $b; # @a now contains 5 elements, last two are undef, 
                            # @count_number contains one elements: the number 5

print @count_number;        # you print the contents of @count_number which is 5
print "\n";
print @a;                   # you print @a which looks like what you started with
                            # but actually contains 2 undefs at the end
```

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $b = 4;
my @a = (1,2,3);
my @b= ("homer", "marge", "lisa", "maria");
my @c= qw(one two three);

print "a contains " . @a . " elements: @a\n";

push @a, $b;
print "now a contains " . @a . " elements: @a\n";

my $count_number = push @a, $b;
print "finally, we have $count_number elements \n";
print "a contains @a\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

$array returns the length of the array (Number of elements in the array) 
To push any element ($k) into the array (@arr), use push (@arr, $k).
In the above case,

use push (@b, @b);